# AWS-RDS: Invalid max storage size for engine name postgres and storage type gp2

Tags: amazon-rds, autoscaling

I'm getting this error while modifying DB instance. `Invalid max storage size for engine name postgres and storage type gp2: 198` for schedule autoscaling.

This never happened before, just yesterday and today. Below is the current storage configuration of the DB instance. Does anyone know where this error came from?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Databases can only be increased by 5GB or 10% which ever is greater

Comment: Just for completeness, do you know if this limit is hard, or can AWS Support increase it on a per-account basis?